# Android Paging 3 Library - Update 1st page VH with next loads

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library

With Paging 3 Library, is it possible to update a ViewHolder of the 1st page when the 2nd page loads, instead of inserting new items ? My displayed data is grouped by date (nested RecyclerView), and the 2nd load can sometimes contain items dated from a 1st page ViewHolder.

### Example

1st page network request :

```
Jan 1st 2020 - X Y Z

Jan 2nd 2020 - A B
```

2nd page network request :

```
Jan 2nd 2020 - E F
```

I would like my main RecyclerView to contain only 2 items after these 2 network requests :

```
Jan 1st 2020 - X Y Z
Jan 2nd 2020 - A B E F
```

### Clarification about the network response

My API returns the data this way :

```
X - Jan 1st 2020
Y - Jan 1st 2020
Z - Jan 1st 2020
A - Jan 2nd 2020
B - Jan 2nd 2020
```

I tried to insert my data in a Room DB with a one-to-many relationship between dates and items, but Room do not support the generation of PagingSource of one-to-many related objects as of 2.3.0-alpha01.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to edit existing items this is probably best done with a layered approach using `RemoteMediator`.

Your `PagingSource` implementation would be based on locally cached data (Room would be a good candidate here) and when the local cache runs out of data, `RemoteMediator` could be triggered to fetch more items, then would query for existing items out of the cache, modify them and insert the new items, then invalidate the `PagingSource` so it becomes aware of the new changes.

Invalidation is currently the only way to update existing data outside of transformations. We'd like to add new operators, but don't yet have something like a `fold` / `reduce` / `deduplicate` that would fit this use-case.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that my data is returned as a list of A B E F X Y Z and so on. If I understand what you are saying, I should cache these data in the form I display them (already grouped by date). Is it OK if the PagingSource returns a page of 2 items (2 distinct dates) even if my network call returned, say, 15 (dispatched between those 2 dates) ?

Comment: I just tried that and it does not seem to work in my case since Room cannot create PagingSource getter for one-to-many mapping objects. I cannot get my list of dates with the associated items that way